# Does TypeScript allow one to map typings from an array of keys to an object with keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to add types for a library with an interesting API. To simplify the problem, it's a function that takes this:

```
const payload = {
  returns: {
    users: ['user1', 'user2'],
    posts: ['post1', 'post2'],
  }
}
```

And turns it into an object with this shape:

```
{
  users: {
    user1: any
    user2: any
  }
  posts: {
    post1: any
    post2: any
  }
}
```

The main problem I'm seeing is that TypeScript infers those arrays as `string[]` rather than as constants. I would normally do `as const`, but I'm writing these typings to add types to a JS library—so users of the library, who are writing JavaScript, can't use `as const`.

Edit: To clarify some more, the reason I'm doing this is because adding types to JavaScript packages is *still* helpful even to JS users, because Intellisense is powered by TypeScript, and a large portion of the company uses VS Code.

Comment: Why wouldn't `as const` should just get compiled away? Javascript environments should not be importing typescript files directly, ever.

Comment: @AlexWayne I edited to clarify—I'm writing a declaration file for a pre-existing JS library, used in an all-JS codebase. So the users of this library don't have access to `as const`.

Comment: But if the consumer can't use `as const` then they can't use types, which also makes this somewhat pointless. This can definitely be typed, but typescript would need to get those strings as constants somehow to know how to transform them.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the goal here: are these JavaScript-writing library users [running `tsc` to check their JS code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html)?  If so, you can do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJz5W) to simulate `as const`. If not, then I really am not clear about what you're trying to do.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I'll clarify more. No, we're not explicitly typechecking as part of any build step or anything like that. This is just so that users of the library at my company get some nice Intellisense for this function. We try to add types to internal tools as much as possible so that even though people are using JS, they still get a nice developer experience (at least, people using editors that support the TS language server).

Comment: I didn't know TS intellisense worked in JS. That's neat I suppose, but I imagine you'll have to settle for greatly reduced control over how types are declared/used/inferred. For what it's worth, if this was pure TS then something like this would work: https://tsplay.dev/vwjG1N

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/ewe1Bw) meet your needs?  I'm not sure if you're looking to write actual `.d.ts` files or if you want to use JSDOC for typing things, but either way you should be able to get some typing for JS users if they are willing to do something *like* `asConstish(xyz)`  in place of `xyz as const`.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I was getting at—whether it's possible to get TS to infer this without the user having to add `as const`. Even if we were using TS fully, it would be nice to avoid making users add that. I appreciate the playground, helps to show why it's not possible :)

Comment: You can indeed avoid having users write `as const` if they are willing to pass their payload into the function as an object literal directly.  By saving it to a variable like `payload` first, however, you're asking TS to infer the type and the normal heuristics are going to interpret a string array as a `string[]` and not some tuple of specific string literals.

Comment: Oh, I just did the `const payload` thing for the sake of the question. Folks definitely pass this in directly to the function. Let me see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/1WGy2N) then?  If that helps then I can write it up.

Comment: Yes!! It works. Thanks a ton. I'm using .d.ts files but I can convert this to that easily. I just didn't have enough TS tools under my belt to get the generics right. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TS type checker uses certain heuristics to infer types for values.  Generally speaking a variable initialized with array literal of strings like `const arr = ["foo", "bar"]` will be inferred to be of type `Array<string>`, because oftentimes developers will go on to modify the contents of arrays.  If it were to infer the type of `arr` as, say, `Array<"foo" | "bar">`, developers would find themselves unable to put any strings other than `"foo"` or `"bar"` into the array... which would be pretty annoying.

There are times, however, where the type checker can be persuaded to infer things more narrowly.  The shortest and least "wacky" way of doing this is probably to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) via `as const`.  The problem here is that it requires the person *creating* the value to do the assertion.  In your case this would be users of the library, and you don't want to burden them with that.  It's even worse for you because they are writing JavaScript, and there isn't currently a JSDoc version of `as const`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30445](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30445) for an open feature request to support this.  [**UPDATE** this will be fixed in TS4.5, see [microsoft/TypeScript#45464](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45464)]

---

You'd prefer your library function *call signature* to be able to ask for a narrower type.  Essentially to behave *as if* the caller had put `as const` in there.  Sadly there is no analogously simple way of writing such a call signature.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for an open feature request (filed by me fwiw) to allow something like this.

For now, we have to use the "wacky" ways of doing this.  If you want the type checker to see a string like `"foo"` and not widen it to `string`, one way to do it is to have it match up with a *generic type parameter* like `K extends string` instead of just `string`.  Even though the compiler might not *infer* `K` to be anything useful, it will allow things that *depend* on `K` to stay narrow.  It's wacky, I know.  I go into this in microsoft/TypeScript#30680.

Here's one possible signature:

```
declare function transform<
    T extends Record<keyof T, readonly K[]>,
    K extends string
>(obj: { returns: T }): { [K in keyof T]: { [P in T[K][number]]: any } };
```

It takes a param of type `{returns: T}`, where `T` is some object whose properties are `K` arrays, where `K extends string`.  Again, we're just doing that instead of `string[]` to cause the type checker to keep track of string literals passed to it:

```
const transformed = transform({
    returns: {
        users: ['user1', 'user2'],
        posts: ['post1', 'post2'],
    }
})
/* const transformed: {
    users: {
        user1: any;
        user2: any;
    };
    posts: {
        post1: any;
        post2: any;
    };
} */
```

Hooray!

---

Of course this will fail if the caller assigns the payload to a new variable before passing it into `transform()`.  Any hints or other demands that the type checker infer string literals from the function input will be useless if the function input's type has already been widened to something where it has forgotten the string literals.  At that point you need to ask users to use `as const` or something similar (for JS users you can make an identity `asConstish()` function that looks like the `foo()` function from microsoft/TypeScript#30680).  Or just tell users not to save it to a variable first.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZ2HFBbAHgChFTEAVRAUwA8oqwATTRAJSol0YIGsqBPOMAoAaRCippGCADb9EAaQDaAXQB8IkmQXU6DZokyoYYAOZE1ACjgAjAFYAuRAG9xVKCBRYnlAL4BKJ1clHRNEPkFhchUgxCUABUQw8hCVJTAQPBsqFBUYxAx5X0Ri5y1SCQ8vRAB5ew4oADpgFDg8AFEwYypMS3KyUks6uwbGhm7e2ztGys8sfwKWAEEUdH4CJQihUUNjM1V1f0a8NAAHPoHLsktNsQA3FQWAXjU4-qurnjFh0Za2zomljuxzOlh4iBecS+iAAjAAmADMj387w+KlRpBRAwWaBYhQA3ERfEQSUROFgoMh0FgcPgqIwIVSMNhcHhLGUBrMvJgghjECBMDkeXEAOQCnIwkViMWClBwkUqTQfRCnOBGYVKEWqoyS6XaqDyxX9YkBIgAegAVIhyUYmTTWfTeQNxShhRyPi6YU4CXyXXDvWB+ISBr5g2R9W6+fqvQVA2Grvr-bGg8bCcULWayQhMHAZFRGjI4KZLKhmbS8PSUUA)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. You understood my problem, listed out the possible steps I could've taken but that would have failed, and gave a solution. Thanks a bunch!